# Modeling Linear Functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This may be an easy question but I'm having trouble finding answers. I've tried getting a variable on one side and doing simple division but the models I make don't match up with the results.

My objective is to make a linear equation in the form of 'y = mx + b' to model the behaviour of crickets chirping at different temperatures. A cricket produces 113 chirps at 70 degrees and 173 chirps at 80 degrees.

I know this is probably grade-school simple and I'm a little embarrassed of asking help but I was hoping somebody could walk me through the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were given that the cricket produces 113 chirps at 70 degrees and 173 chirps at 80 degrees. So the points $(70,113)$ and $(80,173)$ are in the graph of your function. So by the slope-point formula: $$m=\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=\dfrac{173-113}{80-70}=\dfrac{60}{10}=6.$$
So your equation will have the form $y=6x+b.$ To find $b$ just plug in some values and you get an equation with one unknown, like: $$113=6\cdot 70+b.$$ Solve it and you get your final equation.